# Does calorie count on a can of beer account for calories in the alcohol?

Tags: nutrition

I was having a discussion with a friend about the amount of calories in various kinds of beer, light beers and seltzers and he said that the calorie information in the nutrition section of the can does not account for the amount of calories you gain when your body metabolizes the alcohol.

Is he correct?

Answer (score 2):

I have no a priori knowledge. But I can Google. Evidently the calorie count does include the calories from alcohol (see [here](https://www.seriouseats.com/cocktail-science-do-alcohol-calories-count-digesting-spirits)). This is because the method for determining calories comes from basically burning the sample. However, calories from alcohol are not efficiently digested so the listed calorie count in beer is higher than what is actually digested.

Comment: In a word: It is complicated.